# Safely returning float value in threads

Tags: c, posix

i wish to make a thread return a float value.
Changing the data type from float to long works fine, but not with float.
Any help? Thanks.

```
void * funcFloat(void * arg){
    float x = *(float *)arg;
    printf("Received: %f\n", x);
    return (void *)x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer indicates, your original problem is that you're returning the float itself (`x`) when you should be returning a pointer to it.

As for your comment about getting the return value with `pthread_join()`, note its prototype:

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

It takes a **pointer** to a `void *` in the second argument, which is why calling `pthread_join(tf, (void *)&z);` where `z` is a `float` does not work. Here's a working example, minus error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * funcFloat(void * arg){
    float x = *(float *)arg;
    printf("Received: %f\n", x);
    float *returnf = malloc(sizeof(returnf));
    *returnf = x;
    return returnf;
}

main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t thread;
    float f = 3.14159;
    float f2;
    float *joinedf = NULL;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, funcFloat, &f);
    pthread_join(thread, (void **)&joinedf);
    f2 = *joinedf;
    free(joinedf);

    printf("final: %f\n", f2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
void * funcFloat(void * arg){
   return arg;
}
```

Or

```
 void * funcFloat(void * arg){

     float * f = malloc(sizeof(f));
     *f = 1.2345667f;
     return f;
 }
```

Then get the owner of the return value to tidy up

Comment: Using
pthread_join(tf, (void *)&z);
does not seem to work, any suggestion?

Comment: What is `z`? Apart from a character in pulp fiction!

Comment: In main, i declared z as float. I wish to save the value returned by the thread in this variable.